# can't multiply a double by a BigDecimal

Tags: tostring, bigdecimal, multiplication

```
public BigDecimal calcularPrecioEnDolares(BigDecimal precio)
{
   return precioEnDolares = precio.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.14));

}
public String toString() {

    return "El piso con número de referencia " + this.numeroDeReferencia + ", " + "se encuentra en la población de "+ this.poblacion
            + ", situado en la zona de " + this.zona
            + ", calle " + this.calle
            + ", portal " + this.portal
            + ", planta " + this.planta + ", escalera " + this.escalera + ". \nTiene un total de " + this.metrosCuadrados +
            " metros cuadrados, " + this.annosDeAntiguedad +" años de antigüedad, " + this.numeroDeHabitaciones + " habitaciones y " 
            + this.numeroDeBannos + " baños. \n Además, en este piso " + this.animales + " se permiten animales y " + 
            this.muebles + " está amueblado. \n" + this.extras + "\n El precio de este piso es de " + nfe.format(this.precio) + " /mes o " + 
            nfu.format(this.precioEnDolares) + "/mes.";
}
```

When I run the program it tells me I can't write the Object "precio" as a number. Do you now how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Looks like Java. I've edited the tags so more java people can help with this.

Comment: "the program it tells me I can't write the Object 'precio' as a number" Can you be more accurate? What happens, a compiler error? Or a runtime exception? Can you post the exact message please.